# jQuery button not calling and removing GeoJson Layer on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to create a button using jquery that will turn a geoJSON layer in Leaflet on and off. The tileLayer pops up in my html page and my geoJSON file shows on my map. The button I created shows just above the map I created as well The bind pop up function works too.

However whenever I click the button, the console in google chrome tells me this (this is what happens when I clicked my button three times, if I continute it keeps telling t.onRemove is not a function:

```
    leaflet.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
        at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:6)
        at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
        at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (Leaflet.html:62)
        at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
        at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

    leaflet.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: t.onRemove is not a function
        at e.removeLayer (leaflet.js:6)
        at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (Leaflet.html:60)
        at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
        at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

   leaflet.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: t.onRemove is not a function
        at e.removeLayer (leaflet.js:6)
        at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (Leaflet.html:60)
        at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
        at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I have all my source jquery and javascript imported.
I followed this tutorial and have the code written exactly as he does:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qhj_vIKrASc

He has a line of code that I don't and I think this may be the problem. He puts it just after my button div I created called layerButt.

```
<button id="blank><a href="index_blank.html">
```

Here is a copy of my code. I am not that experienced of a coder and have been trying to get this to work for 4 days now. I greatly appreciate your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet Loading GeoJSON</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layerbutton.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab'      rel='stylesheet'
text='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />

</head>
<body>
<h1>My map</h1>
<div id='mapdiv' style='height:500px;'>here lies a map.</div>
<div id="tileBar"> 
<div class="layerButt" id="pointButt"><h3> TTC On/Off</h3></div> 
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ttc.js"></script>

<script>
// <script> powers up script
    var mymap = L.map('mapdiv').setView([43,-79],8);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3BhdGlhbGFydHMiLCJhIjoiY2l3c2NlcnJkMTR1YTJ5dGJzYTJuZ3oyMSJ9.qIr2uFfZbZzrDHaJBccYeQ', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    minZoom: 6,
    maxZoom: 16,
//choose project id/dataset from map box studio
    id: 'n/a,(and chose not to add this, the tile layer opens )
//accessToken id from map box account
    accessToken: n/a (I chose not to add this, the tile layer does open)

}).addTo(mymap); 

function attach (feature,layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<h1 class='infoHeader'> Toronto TTC Subway Name</h1><p     class='infoHeader'>" + feature.properties.SBWAY_NAME +"</p>");
};

    L.geoJSON(ttc,{

        onEachFeature: attach

}).addTo(mymap);


// closes script 
</script>

<script>

$("#pointButt").click(function(){

    if(mymap.hasLayer(ttc)){
        mymap.removeLayer(ttc);
    } else {
        mymap.addLayer(ttc);
    };

});

</script>
```

Here is the code to my css

```
html, body, #mapdiv{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.layerButt{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: black;
    font-size: 22px; 
    font-family: Roboto Slab;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
}

#tileBar {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Your time is greatly appreciated.

Regards.